# Xamarin Webforms (Webview)

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am loading my entire website through url. I need a way to save username and password sins I am not using any codes in the xamarin project. I have no idea how to do so, I am relatively new to this area.

Answer (score 0):

The `WebViewClient` class has a callback method `OnReceivedHttpAuthRequest` which is invoked by the WebView when the server wants a user name and password. One of the parameters on this method is an `HttpAuthHandler` interface. You control the authorization request by calling methods on this handler.

So the solution is to create a `WebViewClient` subclass that overrides `OnReceivedHttpAuthRequest` and calls the appropriate method on the `HttpAuthHandler`. Then set your WebView to have an instance of this subclass.

Here's the link to the Xamarin documentation: [OnReceivedHttpAuthRequest - Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/Android.Webkit.WebViewClient.OnReceivedHttpAuthRequest?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9#Android_Webkit_WebViewClient_OnReceivedHttpAuthRequest_Android_Webkit_WebView_Android_Webkit_HttpAuthHandler_System_String_System_String_).

```
var client = new MyWebViewClient();
WebView web = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
web.SetWebViewClient(client);

class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient {

public override void OnReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, string host, string realm) {

    handler.Proceed(username, password);
 }
}
```